# WPF XAML properties evaluated flag

Tags: wpf

I am writing this user control, and I need to know when XAML parser has evaluated all the properties. I know that Loaded event will only get called when setters of all properties have been called. That is one way. But then I will have to manually maintain a flag indicating it. Is there any ways I can query in a setter if XAML parsing part is done and I am now in a user edit mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the [`FrameworkElement.IsLoaded`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.isloaded.aspx) property? Is this what you want?

Comment: That is what I was looking for... how the hell did I miss it